# Either 'name', or 'model' and 'attribute' properties must be specified

Tags: yii2

estoy usando la extension yii-grid y se me genera un error al intentar ejecutar mi programa.

```
     use kartik\grid\GridView;

   <?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
       'idissues',
         'issuetype_idissuetype',
        'Description',
         'title',
         'comment',
         'date',
         [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'pageSummary' => 'Page Total',
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-sticky-column'],
    'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-sticky-column'],
    'editableOptions'=>['header'=>'status', 'size'=>'md']
     ],

  [
   'attribute' => 'issuescol',
   'label' => 'Prioridad',
   'encodeLabel' => false,
   //'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
   'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
    return ['class' => 'label-'.FunctionName($model['issuescol'])];


        },
   ],


      [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header'=>'Ver Resumen',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
            'template' => '{view}',
            'buttons' => [
              'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                  return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye- 
    open"></span>', $url, [
                  'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Ver Descripcion de Issues'),
                  ]);


              }
            ],
          'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {



              if ($action === 'view') {


                  $url = Url::to(['/issues/view', 'idissues' =>$model['idissues'],'project_idproject'=>$model['project_idproject']]);
              return $url;
              }
              //issues%2Fview&idissues=5&project_idproject=6
              //issues%2Fview&1%5Bidissues%5D=1&1%5Bproject_idproject%5D=1
          }           

      ],

  ],

  ]);
```

Comment: En qué linea te marca el error?

Comment: Por favor muestra el error concreto y el controlador desde el que renderizas la vista.